# Using Two nested Try blocks and a Single Catch block in Java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, try-with-resources

I'm learning about Java and exception handling and the `try/catch` blocks. And I'm doing an example from YouTube, and I want to ask you if this is a pattern or something when you use 2 `try` blocks and one `catch` block:

```
private List<User> parseCSVFile(final MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                final String[] data = line.split(",");
                final User user = new User();
                user.setName(data[0]);
                user.setEmail(data[1]);
                user.setGender(data[2]);
                users.add(user);
            }
            return users;
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to parse CSV file {}", e);
        throw new Exception("Failed to parse CSV file {}", e);
    }
}
```

I try to understand why this approach is better than using a `try` and a `catch` block like this:

```
try (final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        final String[] data = line.split(",");
        final User user = new User();
        user.setName(data[0]);
        user.setEmail(data[1]);
        user.setGender(data[2]);
        users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
} catch (final IOException e) {
    logger.error("Failed to parse CSV file {}", e);
    throw new Exception("Failed to parse CSV file {}", e);
}
```

Comment: I definitely feel that the second example is better. The first one contains more code and is harder to read. On a side note, it's bad practice to throw `Exception` or `RuntimeException`. In this case even more so, because the file comes from a file upload. Something that leads to a 400 error response is much better.

Comment: There is no point in doing that, the only "gain" is more code nesting, which is totally not a gain...

Comment: @Rob, what exception should I throw instead of Exception? Do you want to say to create a custom exception and for the API request the status should be 400?

Comment: @elvis You could create an `InvalidCSVException` or something like that (assuming that this is the only possible cause of the `IOException`). The API should then map this (a custom `ExceptionHandler` perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

Two nested `try`-blocks in the first code snippet are redundant. When an exception occurs, it would be propagated until the point where it can be handled (or otherwise the execution would terminate).

Regarding the usage of `try`-blocks, you need to understand that it doesn't make sense having `try` without `catch` or `finally` (and compiler will **not** allow that).

**Note** that in case of *try-with-resources* `try(myResource){}`, you **do have** an implicit `finally`-block, therefore even without a `catch`-block *try-with-resources* can be useful and perfectly valid from the compiler perspective of view.

*For more information on exception-handling refer to the [official tutorial provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).*

Comment: If there's a genuine problem with the answer, I would appreciate if you spend a minute of your time describing the issue.

Comment: Initializer of resource is executed outside of `try` so outer `try` needed to catch such exception.

Comment: @talex In code provided in the question resources are being initialized in by the means of *try-with-resources*, and it is not clear why the second `try` block might be needed neither from your comment, no from your answers which exposes the code that would fail to compile (because of the lonely `catch` without `try`).

Comment: @talex In case if you didn't notice, I was commenting the snippet of code provided in the question (**not* any arbitrary case).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Looks like java changed behavior of `try-with-resource`, so my answer is no longer valid.

It did explains why you can see double `try` in some old tutorials.

**ORIGINAL POST**

Try with resources is syntactic sugar.

```
try(A a = foo()){
   bar();
} catch (E e) {
}
```

is equivalent of

```
A a = foo();
try {
   bar();
} catch (E e) {
} finally {
   a.close();
}
```

Which mean exception thrown from `foo` won't be caught. therefore you need another `try ... catch`.

Comment: It was useful before behavior was changed.